# ess-toggle-underscore doesn't work

Tags: r, emacs, ess

Normally, when using ESS, adding the `(ess-toggle-underscore nil)` line to the .emacs file stops the automatic conversion of underscores to `<-`. Recently this has stopped working and underscores are converted to arrows even when the option above is present in the .emacs file.

Does anybody know why this is?

My emacs version is: `23.4.1`

My R version is: `2.15.1`

My ess version is: `12.04-4-1`

Comment: ... That's an interesting version of R you have installed

Comment: My guess is that it's almost certainly a matter of the option not getting loaded or getting overwritten. (I'm running ess 13.03, emacs 23.3.1 and R-3.0.0 and have never had any problems). Some ideas: (1) Check that the option is available and works by doing `M-x ess-toggle-underscore`; (2) Make sure that your .emacs file doesn't have some error in it that interrupts its loading before the `(ess-toggle-underscore nil)` gets read; (3) check that something later in your file doesn't reset `ess-toggle-underscore` for you.

Comment: You're right Josh. A previous line had an error. Thanks!